# DbContext Set with where query using database first approach EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, ef-database-first

I have a database first project with ADO.NET Entity Data model generated classes. All of my classes have same boolean and datetime fields, Ok and Date. I want to create generic method for retrieving T class from DbContext but i'm not sure how to use where in that query since i cant access Ok and Date fields.

note: i can't change generated classes, and i would want to avoid using Linq.Dynamic

ADO.Net generated

```
public partial class First
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NameFirst { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool Ok { get; set; }
}

public partial class Second
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NameSecond { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool Ok { get; set; }
}
```

Retrieve data

```
public List<SomeModel> LoadFromDatabase<T>(bool ok, DateTime date)
{
    var dbData = DbContext.Set(typeof(T)).AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Ok ??? );

    //remap to some model and return it
    ...

    return someModel;
}
```

Edit 1:

```
public List<SomeModel> LoadFromDatabase<T>(bool ok, DateTime date) where T : IDateOk 
{
    var dbData = DbContext.Set(typeof(T)).AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Ok &&);

    //remap to some model and return it
    ...

    return someModel;
}

public interface IDateOk {
    DateTime Date { get; set; }
    bool Ok { get; set; }
}
```

Edit 2:
I was missing class in method so it should be like this

```
public List<SomeModel> LoadFromDatabase<T>(bool ok, DateTime date) where T : class IDateOk
```

Answer (score 1):

Define an interface for the common properties:

```
public interface IDateOk {
    DateTime Date { get; set; }
    bool Ok { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a tutorial how to add the interface to the generated classes:
[Getting the Entity Framework to Generate an Interface for Mocking](https://slappyza.wordpress.com/2010/08/08/getting-the-entity-framework-to-generate-an-interface-for-mocking/)

Constrain your method to require this interface:

```
public List<SomeModel> LoadFromDatabase<T>(bool ok, DateTime date) where T: IDateOk
```

Now you should be able to access OK and Date in the implementation.

Comment: I made changes you suggested you can see them in Edit 1, unfortunately i get  "Cannot resolve symbol Ok" in dbData query. Do you know why?

Comment: Hm maybe I did not think this through and EF can not translate the query into SQL. To test this hypothesis, please try to run the query in memory by enumerating first: `var dbData = DbContext.Set(typeof(T)).AsNoTracking().ToList().Where(x => x.Ok);`

Comment: Thank you for your help it led me to final solution